# Alternative to ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Hey, I've been getting some beans from my webhost setting up support for MSFT's ReportViewer.
Are there any good alternatives you can recommend?

Comment: my host took so long to deal with this, i ended up using the datagrid and writing custom 'export to excel' and 'export to pdf' functions. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is Crystal Reports - check this breakdown out [Crystal Reports vs ReportViewer Pros/Cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149118/crystal-reports-vs-reportviewer-pros-cons)

Answer (score 0):

Jasper reports is another alternative. it is open source and written in Java.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library