# Difference between MS Report Viewer and Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crystal Reports vs ReportViewer Pros/Cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149118/crystal-reports-vs-reportviewer-pros-cons)

Could any body tell me what is the difference between MS Report Viewer and Crystal Report Viewer?  I need to display some basic info. from my database and donot want to install any additional programs on client's computer to run the report, which type is better for me?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149118/crystal-reports-vs-reportviewer-pros-cons). I think Martín Marconcini said it best  in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149118/crystal-reports-vs-reportviewer-pros-cons/280977#280977).

> Crystal Reports is the "one-stop shop"
>   that the user see as the "heaven made"
>   reporting engine and turns out to be
>   overbloated, crowded with bugs and
>   license reqs.

Crystal Reports is very nasty to develop on. Stay away from it if you can.